# VC12 Command Line Error when Linking .lib Files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compilation, linker

I'm trying to compile a C++ program from the VS2013 command window with includes and linked libraries. Pretty standard stuff. However, Microsoft's [website explaining the syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx) is not very clear to me.

I'm trying the following command:

```
cl /EHsc program.cpp /I "\path\to\includes"
    /LIBPATH:"\path\to\library\directory" /LINK libfile1.lib libfile2.lib
```

*Note: It's all on one line when I execute it, but for readability I've split it here.*

The quotes are because some of the directories in the paths have whitespace in them beyond my control (like Program Files).

I'm trying to adapt this command from a property sheet I made using the Visual Studio interface, so if it helps, the mapping I'm making is:

- IncludePath --> [/I](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx)
- LibraryPath --> [/LIBPATH:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe.aspx)
- AdditionalDependencies (under Link) --> [/LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcce369f.aspx)

I am running this as an admin in the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt on a machine running 64-bit Windows 10. However, it gives me these warnings and errors:

```
cl: Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/LIBPATH:\path\to\library\directory'
cl: Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/LINK'
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libfile1.lib'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps show the actual command line (using the actual directory paths and file names) and error message - use copy/paste to ensure the exact characters are posted in the question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Everything is copied and pasted from the output. I've just changed the directory paths and filenames with find/replace, so it should be as exact as needed

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I think my issue really lies with the command options. I'm not quite sure I'm using them correctly, hene the D9002 warnings

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure there's no character that might need to be escaped (or otherwise weird/wrong) in the strings you're replacing.  If you copy/pasted and did a correct replace as you state, note that you're missing the double-quote character that terminates that libpath argument : `/LIBPATH:"\path\to\library\directory /LINK libfile1.lib libfile2.lib`

Comment: You're right... my bad--fixed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/link` option must be lowercase and place the `/LIBPATH` option after it:

```
cl /EHsc program.cpp /I "\path\to\includes" /link /LIBPATH:"\path\to\library\directory" libfile1.lib libfile2.lib
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! Is there a particular reason LIBPATH goes second?

Comment: @marcman It's because you are taking the shortcut of compiling and linking in one `cl` command, rather than compiling with `cl` and then
linking with `link`. `cl` will invoke the linker for you if you tell it `/link [linker_option...] link_files`. `/LIBPATH` is a linker option, not a compiler option.

Answer (score -1):

try to add the lib's path to your Library Directories (Configuration Properties >> VC++ Directories).

and compile again

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio for this program, just the compiler. As a result this solution won't work.